# Jmeter - How to Loop with requests?

Tags: loops, controller, jmeter, python-requests, logic

So, this is the case:

I have one admin user that has to:

1- Access the Homepage;

2- Access the admin panel;

3- Access the courses catalog;

4- Search (by text) for the course;

5- Select and edit the course subscriptions;

6- Enters in the first class of the course (here's the point that i need to loop, i have 708 classes);

7- Marks all students in that class;

8- Click on "student present";

9- Click on save.

So, I have all this 708 classes and i got to loop at the step 6 and on (708 times).

The question: How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My expectation is that at some stage at point 4 or 5 you get the list of classes in the response from your application so you should be able to extract all classes IDs using a suitable JMeter [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors), i.e. [Regular Expression Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-regular-expressions-jmeter/)

Given you provide `-1` as the "Match No." the Regular Expression Extractor will create 708 JMeter Variables which can be iterated using i.e. [ForEach Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add your cases to CSV file and add CSV Data Set Config to JMeter which connected to

Then for Step 6 add as a parent [ForEach_Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) with variable name set in CSV Data Set Config

> ForEach controller loops through the values of a set of related variables. When you add samplers (or controllers) to a ForEach controller, every sample (or controller) is executed one or more times, where during every loop the variable has a new value